# How to check if webview action has done

Tags: flutter, webview

I display a web page in my app ,this is a payment page
Want to check if the process done (if the user clicked the submit button),but the navigationDelegate function of webview doesn't print anything

[image: I haved used webview_flutter package]

Comment: Navigation delegate will trigger only when url updates if your site is not update or requesting a new URL it will not be detected by webView navigation

Comment: Please [edit] your post to include the minimum code needed to reproduce the problem as text, not as a image